# Manage auto-scaled instances in Route53

Tags: amazon-web-services, autoscaling, amazon-elb, amazon-route53

In AWS, what is the right way to add and remove instance managed by AutoScaling Configuration in Route53 record sets?

I cannot use ELB because application instances need to handle UDP traffic, which is not supported by ELBs.

Answer (score 1):

I remember seeing that [Loggly did the same thing](https://www.loggly.com/blog/why-aws-route-53-over-elastic-load-balancing/), using Route53 because they had UDP traffic.

Basically, [use a routing policy](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/routing-policy.html). 'Simple' is the easiest, but 'Failover' or 'Latency' may be better choices. Most importantly, it's important to enable [health checks](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/dns-failover.html).